# using getch() to affect conditionals

Tags: c, if-statement, random, while-loop, getch

I'm trying to use getch() as a way to shift between conditionals, such that if the user enters a specific character, the condition that holds true in the if-statement will be invalid and the "else" code will then execute. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    int k = 1;
    char k_char = k + '0';
    int r;

    while(1){

        int n = getch();

        if (n == 'a'){
            k = 0;
        }

        if(k == 1){
            r = rand() % 999;
            printf("%d\n", r);
            napms(300);
        }
        else{
            r = rand() % 4;
            printf("%d\n", r);
            napms(300);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

entering 'a' doesn't do anything... and I'm having trouble figuring out why, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: "entering 'a' doesn't do anything..." --> Try `a`, `<Enter>` as `stdin` is usually _line buffered_.

Comment: @chux if you mean entering 'a' and then pressing 'enter,' that doesn't work.

Comment: so when you enter `a` and press Enter, literally nothing happens?

Comment: @M.M the numbers that get printed out continue to be between 0 and 999 just as they were before, so nothing changes.

Comment: It would be better to describe exactly what *does* happen, instead of saying things like "doesn't work", "doesn't do anything", nobody can tell what you mean by those things.

Comment: @laroy Is posted code the _exact_ code you are using?  What is the exact input?  What is the exact output?  How many numbers where printed with only entering `a`, `<Enter>`?

Comment: Could this be from mixing C Standard IO functions with `ncurses` IO functions?

Comment: @chux the posted code is the EXACT code I'm using, all I try to do is input 'a' and the output is a series of numbers between 0 and 999 both before and after I enter 'a'. (like so) --> 

823
7
347
587
184
953
672
a
188
161
955
828
719
762
359
909
164
52
^C

Comment: @DavidBowling possibly, though I don't really know anything about that or how I would fix it.

Comment: Changing both `printf("%d\n", r);` to `printf("%d %d\n", r, n);` would be illuminating.  I suspect `getch();` returns even without keyboard input.  Maybe as 0 or EOF.

Comment: In "823 7 347 587 184 953 672 a 188 161 955 828 719 762 359 909 164 52" it's not clear what is input or output or when things happened... I guess you typed the `a` but what about the other numbers? What keys are you pressing between the other numbers? You really do need to explain exactly what you did

Comment: @M.M yes... a is the input, the other numbers are the output as expected from the if-statement. No other keys are pressed.

Comment: I think that your issue is that `ncurses` input/output functions should not be used with Standard I/O functions. If you call `initscr()` at the start of the program, use the `ncurses` function `printw()` instead of `printf()`, and call `refresh()` after the `printw()`s, I think that code will behave. Also, you must then call `endwin()` before program exit.

Comment: @DavidBowling, you're absolutely right. I think this may have led me to the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me:

```
if(getch() == 'a'){statement}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not calling `initscr` or `newterm` your terminal is not initialized and will be in default mode for input (so "special" input and output won't work properly).

In the case of `getch` it means that the terminal is probably still in canonical/echo mode, so characters won't be read (it will block/wait) until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, and all characters will be echoed by the terminal regardless of the `echo`/`noecho` setting.

Easiest fix is just to add calls to `initscr();` and `cbreak();` to the beginning of main.  Possibly also `noecho();` and `nodelay(stdscr, 1);` or `halfdelay(n);` if you want those features as well.

It would also be good to put in a signal handler to call `endwin()` before exiting in the case of SIGINT or SIGTERM.